# set navigationBar background image in swift

Tags: uinavigationbar, swift, ios8

Code below is not working for me, can anyone help to figure it out what is wrong?

```
var image = UIImage(named: "10384605_10152519403846670_5189785375955620548_n.jpg") as UIImage

self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image , forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, 
                                                   forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: How to set image for the back button?

Comment: Is it no longer working? I'm trying this code with iOS 12 and Xcode 10 but it's not working. The image is shown for a second and then the NavigationBar turns only white and without the separator line and shadow...

Comment: for swift 4.2 => `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .default)`

Answer (score 16):

In AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Image Background Navigation Bar
    let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "backgroundNB.png")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 14):

In **Swift 3**:

If you want to add a repeating image in the background you can make this call in AppDelegate > didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageNameInAsset")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
```

If you want to add an image to the center of the navigation bar you need to do this in the ViewController > viewWillAppear:

```
let titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageNameInAsset"))
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Answer (score 9):

**If you want to fill the image in navigation bar just use the code:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your_Background_Image_Name")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "navbar_bg")

[UINavigationBar .appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics:.Default)]
```

Comment: Code only answers tend to be regarded as low quality.  Can you edit your answer and add an explanation as how this resolves the issue?

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 3**:

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"pattern.png"),
                                                                for: .default)
```

**OR**

In viewDidLoad():

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"pattern.png"),
     for: .default)
```

Answer (score 2):

set backgroundImage in Navigation controller

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar .setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "cricket"), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 1):

> if You put the navigation bar hidden for the application you have to show it on view did load or appear by :

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("\n Debugger : View will appear called")
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden =  false
}
```

> if you want your navigation bar only show in a specific view controller you have to disappear the navigation bar by :

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("\n Debugger : View did disapper called")

     self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden =  true
}
```

> Navigation bar setup Method

```
private func navigationBarSetup(){

    print("\n Debugger : Navigation Bar setup method called")

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your image name "), for: .default)
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "your Image name"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Your selector method))
    backButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "your Image name"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Your selector method))
    backButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate.swift:

```
    if let myImage = UIImage(named: "navBarImage.jpg"){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(myImage, for: .default)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@benLIVE asked for how to do a back button, which I was doing when I found the accepted answer, so I thought I'd leave this here too (if a bit late) b/c if you are going to replace a nav bar icon, you may as well replace all of them!

```
    let cubeIcon = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
    cubeIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.image = cubeIcon.image
```