# How to add image to top layout

Tags: ios, swift, layout

How to add background image on top layout the one who has back button . ive tried adding imageview on it using the drag and drop but image is hiding on the back. Anyone has an idea?  Thanks

[image: image kindly view]

Comment: "Add background image on top layout the one who has back button" its called `NavigationBar`. You can find [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328363/set-navigationbar-background-image-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: thanks , kindly post an answer so ican vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add background image on top layout the one who has back button

Its called NavigationBar. You can set background image by this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navBG.png"), for: .default)
```

Edit:

> how about adding a label on a navigation bar?

```
self.title = "My Title"
```

Comment: i have to wait 5 minutes ,  i will

Comment: Sir , how about adding a label on a navigation bar?

Comment: @DurnKurvirck See edited answer you can set it by `title` property.

Comment: Another thing , how about adding backgound and title to a nav bar to only certain view controller

Comment: You can change title and background image in every view controller by adding those lines

Comment: Hey Sir are you there?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Background.jpg"), for: .default)
```